# Verbreitung und gefühlte Unhöflichkeit von "Was denn?" im Vergleich zu "Was?" und "Hä?"

Tags: idiom, regional

Ich stelle immer wieder fest, dass ich, wenn ich etwas akustisch nicht richtig verstanden habe, mit **"Was denn?"** (*) nachfrage und das auch als einigermaßen höflich empfinde. Allerdings habe ich mir das erst in Norddeutschland angewöhnt. Als Kind habe ich in Baden-Württemberg gelebt, und mir wurde beigebracht, dass **"Was?"** (so wie **"Hä?"**) unhöflich ist, und man solle **"Wie bitte?"** nutzen.

***Nun meine Frage:*** ist **"Was denn?"** für diejenigen, die es kennen, genauso höflich wie **"Wie bitte?"** oder eher so unhöflich wie **"Was?"**. Wie sieht es für diejenigen aus, die es nicht kennen? Und wo kennt man es überhaupt (aktiv)?

*Edit:* Ich habe noch eine sehr amüsante [Beschreibung eines möglichen Missverständnisses](http://www.netzwort.de/commentarium/index.php?id=314) zwischen "Kennern" und "Nicht-Kennern" gefunden. ([Google-Cache-Version](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3atYQUAQzD3H4J%3awww.netzwort.de/commentarium/index.php%3Fid%3D314&hl=de&gl=de&prmd=imvns&strip=1); dort runterscrollen)

---

(*) Der Ton macht die Musik: ich meine eine gefühlt eher freundliche, nachfragende Betonung die man auch beim "Wie bitte?" anwenden würde, die also auf dem "Was" tief startet und dann auf das "denn" hochgeht. Es ist also *nicht* die genervte "Stör mich nicht"-Betonung, bei der das "Was" höher als das "denn" gesprochen wird.

Comment: Wenn ich das richtig verstehe, verwende ich nichts von alle dem. "Hä" und "Was", sowie auch "Was denn" klingen alle für mich *genervt*, nach dem Motto, lass mich endlich in Ruhe; wobei ich "Was denn" noch nie gehört habe und somit auch mir die Betonung nur schwer vorstellen kann. Persönlich sage ich "Nochmal bitte" oder einfach nur "Sorry" (Betonung als Frage); oder als ganzer Satz "Was hast du gesagt?"

Comment: Ich komme aus Norddeutschland und habe "Was denn" auch noch nie in dem Zusammenhang gehört.

Comment: Könnt Ihr Eure Region etwas genauer eingrenzen? Ich kenne dieses "was denn" bislang von Ostfriesen und Hamburgern...

Comment: *"Entschuldigung, das habe ich jetzt akustisch nicht recht verstanden; könntest Du es bitte noch einmal wiederholen?"* ist kaum besser als *"Hä?" ;P

Comment: Region Eifel ;) Hab es aber letzte Woche in Hamburg nicht einmal gehört ;)

Comment: Ich pflichte Em1 und Hendrik Vogt bei. Wohne über 20 Jahre in Berlin, zähle das auch zu Norddeutschland und habe es auch noch nie gehört. Apropos: Was heißt "gefühlt" hier. Von wem gefühlt, vom Sprecher oder vom Hörer?

Comment: @userunknown: Hm, dann hätte ich vielleicht eher sowas wie "Plattdeutschland" schreiben sollen ;-) Und was das "gefühlt" angeht, so hoffe ich doch, dass es symmetrisch ist. Macht die Sprache oft einfacher...

Comment: @Jan: Was macht die Sprache oft einfacher - Höflichkeit oder der Einschub eines "gefühlt"?

Comment: @userunknown: Symmetrie. Dass das, was von einem gemeint oder gewollt ist, auch beim anderen so ankommt.

Comment: @Jan: Das wäre eher bei mir angekommen, wenn Du es nicht `Symmetrie` genannt hättest. :)

Answer (score 13):

Ich kenne alle vier Varianten und würde keine davon als unhöflich deklarieren, die richtige Betonung vorausgesetzt (was aber schon in der Frage erläutert wurde).

"Hä" klingt in meinen Ohren dämlich und nicht unhöflich. Er hört sich so an, als ob der Sprecher nur über einen eingegrenzten Wortschatz bestehend aus Grunzlauten verfügt. Das ist schade für den Sprecher, aber noch nicht unhöflich. Meine Mutter hat mich dazu erzogen, nicht "Hä" zu verwenden, damit ich nicht wie der letzte Depp klinge.

Insofern: Richtig betont sind alle gleich höflich/unhöflich. Ich kann auch "Wie bitte" so betonen, dass sich andere Leute beleidigt fühlen. (Wobei meines Erachtens viele Leute gerne schnell beleidigt sind aus mir unbekannten Gründen.)

Comment: Halleluja, jemand kennt's! :-D

Comment: @Jan, wann ist der beste Zeitpunkt Dir zu sagen, dass ich nicht aus Norddeutschland komme? ;)

Comment: "Hä" und "Was?" können je nach Kontext und Betonung schneller unhöflich wirken als "Wie bitte" oder "Was denn". Wobei "Was denn" auf mich rein subjektiv wohl in jedem Fall unhöflich wirken würde, selbst wenn es langsam und freundlich daherkäme.

Comment: @JohnSmithers: <lach> - macht nix, ich ja auch nicht :-)

Answer (score 4):

**"Was denn?"**, **"Was?"** und **"Hä?"** klingen *unhöflich*, *rüpelhaft* und zeugen nicht von Intelligenz.
**"Wie bitte?"** klingt dagegen *interessiert* und *höflich*. Kann nur empfehlen, dir das anzugewöhnen.

Comment: Danke für die Empfehlung. Ich möchte Dir im Gegenzug empfehlen, etwas ausführlicher zu antworten und auch klarzustellen, wo Deine Antwort aus Meinung besteht und wo aus Fakten :-)

Comment: Was soll es denn zu umgangsprachlichen Sachen wie "Hä?" oder "Was denn?" für Fakten geben?

Comment: Guter Einwand. Allerdings sollte man Aussagen dazu dann auch nicht als Fakt formulieren.

Comment: @bodycountPP: Es könnte zum Beispiel wissenschaftliche Untersuchungen oder statistische Erhebungen zum Thema geben.

Comment: Intelligenz kommt nur in geringem Maße in der Wortwahl zum Ausdruck. Ich kenne zur Genüge hochintelligente Menschen, die sich oftmals rüpelhaft und unhöflich ausdrücken.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Wobei man in manchen Fällen vielleicht unterscheiden müsste, ob diese einfach gerade heraus sprechen, oder ob sie gezielt für eine rüpelhafte und unhöfliche Ausdrucksweise gewählt haben, um einen bestimmten Effekt zu erreichen ;)

Answer (score 3):

Nach meiner persönlichen Erfahrung des Sprachgebrauchs (NRW) ist die Verwendung von "Was denn?" in dem Sinne wie Du ihn beschreibst unüblich. Zwar ist mir die Bedeutung geläufig, ich würde sie allerdings (auch ohne Deine Information) eher in Norddeutschland erwarten.

Von der Verwendung des Ausdrucks um Genervtheit auszudrücken abgesehen, würde man ihn meiner Einschätzung nach auch stark bei (ironischen) Einwänden verwenden. Etwa so:

> Person 1: Du hast Dir doch nicht ernsthaft einen Staubsauger am Telefon andrehen lassen, oder?
>   Person 2: Was denn? Die haben gesagt der würde viel besser saugen als der, den ich jetzt habe.

Hier wird nicht ausgedrückt die zweite Person habe die erste (etwa akustisch) nicht verstanden, sondern stimmt dem Einwand der ersten einfach nicht zu und legitimiert die kritisierte Handlung. Allerdings klingt für mich hier stark ein ironischer Beigeschmack mit.

Comment: Anders ausgedrückt ist "Was denn?" eine Kurzvariante von "Was ist denn damit nicht in Ordnung?"; "Was ist denn das Problem, wenn ich das getan habe?" etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ich bin aus Österreich (1965 geboren und aufgewachsen in Graz, lebe seit 1997 in Wien). Den Ausdruck "Was denn?" im Sinn von "Wie bitte?" kenne ich überhaupt nicht. Das habe ich noch nie gehört und es käme mir auch nicht in den Sinn, diese Phrase zu verwenden wenn ich etwas nicht verstanden habe.

Ich kenne "Was denn?" und "Was ist denn?" nur im Sinn von "Womit nervst du mich jetzt schon wieder?" und würde es in einem Gespräch auch genau so interpretieren: Als rüpelhafte und extrem unhöfliche Aufforderung meinen Mund zu halten.

Natürlich spielt dabei auch der Tonfall eine Rolle. Man sagt ja, dass 80% der Kommunikation nonverbal stattfinden. Aber auch wenn der Tonfall freundlich bis neutral ist, transportieren die Worte selbst doch eine einigermaßen negative und abweisense Aussage.

Comment: Jan hat in einer Fußnote klargestellt, dass das genervte "Was denn?" nicht gemeint ist.

Answer (score 0):

"Was denn?" benutze ich im normalen Sprachgebrauch gar nicht, da es sich für mich eher als unhöflich (im Sinne von "wer stört mich denn jetzt schon wieder?") anhört.

Es gibt eine einzige Literatur (die mir bekannt ist), der Comic "Gaston", in dem **sinnvoll** "Was denn?" vorkommt. Darin sagt Gaston, der Unglücksbote oder Unglücksrabe, immer dann "Was denn?", wenn eine seiner Aktionen wieder einmal gründlich schief gegangen ist und er seine Überraschung darüber ausdrückt. Sehr lustig. Wie es im französischen Original heißt, weiß ich nicht (ich kann kein Französisch), wäre aber in diesem Zusammenhang interessant.

Um jemandem deutlich zu machen, dass ich etwas nicht verstanden hat, sage ich seltener "Wie bitte?" (nur, wenn ich die betreffende Person gut kenne), besser ist "Entschuldigung, ich habe das nicht verstanden. Könnten Sie es bitte wiederholen?".

"Was?", "Hä?" sind für mich reine Gossensprache.